# I want to list video from a list of channel

Tags: youtube-api

With youtube API, i would like to list video not only for one channel but from a list of channel, 
with listSearch command it would be something like that ? but it's dont work ...

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'maxResults' => _MAX_,
  'type' => "video",
  'order' => 'date',
  "channelId" => "id_channel_1,id_channel_2, ..."
));
```